# Proportion of variance of outcome explained by each variable in a linear regression

Tags: r, variance

In the example data set found below I want to calculate the proportion of variance in science explained by each independent variable using linear regression model.  How could I achieve that in R?

```
hsb2 <- read.table('http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/hsb2.csv', header=T, sep=",")

m1<-lm(science ~ math+female+ socst+ read, data =hsb2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use `anova()` function from `stats` package. 
It gives you the residual sum of squares explained by each variable and total sum of squares (i.e. variance)

```
anova(m1)
 Analysis of Variance Table

 Response: science
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
math        1 7760.6  7760.6 151.8810 < 2.2e-16 ***
female      1  233.0   233.0   4.5599  0.033977 *  
socst       1  465.6   465.6   9.1128  0.002878 ** 
read        1 1084.5  1084.5  21.2254 7.363e-06 ***
Residuals 195 9963.8    51.1                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```